# Javascript button update function name

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I have 6 buttons on the top of my page where the first one is working. When pressing a button I need it to dynamically change the "function name" in my script to match the button "function name". Also for each button I need "tr.cells" to increase +1 which is the next column of my table.

Basically what all this does; my table is 50 Rows 10 Columns that the code looks through for the word "none" if it finds "none" then lines I ID'ed in my document will be hidden.

I have done a hours of research but I am unable get anything to work with my code. I gave an example of what I tried to incorporate but I was unsuccessful. Need it to work with my buttons. I greatly appreciate any help anyone can give. Thank you.

**Example Idea**

```
function F1() { };
function F2() { };

var myFunctions = [F1, F2];

r nextFunction = 0;

function myFunctionSwitcher() {
    myFunctions[nextFunction]();
    nextFunction = nextFunction + 1;
```

**My Code**

```
<td><div align="center"><button onclick = "F1()"> 178-0000-00 </button></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><button onclick = "F2()"> 178-0001-00 </button></div></td>

<script type="text/javascript">


function F1()                                                                /*Change this for "Board Number" #*/
/*Start Loop*/{

var tab = document.getElementById('part1Table');
var l = tab.rows.length;

for ( var i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
    var tr = tab.rows[i];
    var cll = tr.cells[2];                                                              
    if(s = cll.innerText.indexOf('None') != -1) 
    {

var Z = ("")
                    jQuery(function($)
        {
                $('#resultA').load('DocText.html #Tablemain1');

        });;

/* Start Copy */
if (i==1)                                                   /*Change this for "Line in ABI Doc" */
  { var e = document.getElementById('result1');             /*Change this for "Line Hidden" */
        e.style.display = 'none';}
 /* End Copy */
}}} </script>
```

Comment: If the function does the same thing every time, why not just set the same function to all buttons with a variable as an indicator to tell the function if the buttons can run it or not?

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of that. I will look into and see what I can do. Thanks

Comment: I wrote an example in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4SB25/

Comment: jsfiddle just keeps initializing. Do you have to have an account with them? Tried it before but doesn't work. Trying the following. I just need to figure out how to change "m" with button.          var tab = document.getElementById('part1Table');
var l = tab.rows.length;
var m = 2

for ( var i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
    var tr = tab.rows[i];
    var cll = tr.cells[m];                                                              
    if(s = cll.innerText.indexOf('None') != -1) 
 {

Comment: Try through another browser. I'll also write the code in an answer

Comment: Its working in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4SB25/

HTML:

```
<button onclick="func(1)">Button No. 1</button><br>
<button onclick="func(2)">Button No. 2</button><br>
<button onclick="func(3)">Button No. 3</button><br>
<button onclick="func(4)">Button No. 4</button><br>
<button onclick="func(5)">Button No. 5</button><br>
<button onclick="func(6)">Button No. 6</button><br>
<div id="results"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var counter = 1;

function func(id) {
    if (id != counter)
        return;
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML+="Button No. "+id+" was pressed<br>";
    counter++;
}
```

You can use the same logic for the cell number. You set it globally (like the counter variable) with the value of the first cell, and when you update the counter you can update this variable as well.

Comment: I guess because its a counter it only works if I start by pressing button 1. If I need to press any other button first it doesn't work.

Comment: You wrote that you have 6 buttons where the first one is working, and when you press it you want to enable the function for the next button. This is exactly what I did here so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: What I need is to press any one of the buttons to initiate the function and change the value of "tr.cells". Button 1 = 2, Button 2 = 3 and so on. Here is the code I am working with now. I am having a hard time getting the value of "m" to the lower part for "tr.cells". [link](http://jsfiddle.net/johnbl/td75F/)